# Not receiving GCM messages on Android after app is swiped away from recent tasks

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing GCM for push notifications using GcmReceiver and GcmListenerService. When the app is running in the foreground or background, I receive the notifications just fine.

My problem is when I swipe the app away from the "recent tasks" list, I can't receive GCM messages anymore (I am on a Xiaomi Mi3). I understand that if you force close an app, you will not receive push notifications anymore. However, swiping it away from the "recent tasks" should still allow the app to receive push notifications.

I have tested this with WeChat and Facebook Messenger, and I do still receive notifications when I swipe the app away (but not if I force close it from Settings).

What am I doing wrong here?

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.considerdigital.p1mobileapp" >

<permission android:name="com.considerdigital.p1mobileapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.considerdigital.p1mobileapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/p1_app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.P1mobileapp" >

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.considerdigital.p1mobileapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name=".ListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

GcmListenerService:

```
public class ListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

public static final String FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION = "FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION";

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {

    // Send notification only if app is in background
    if (!P1GlobalVariables.getSharedInstance().isAppActive) {
        System.out.println("App is inactive");

        sendNotification(data);
    } else {
        System.out.println("App is active");

        sendForegroundNotification(data);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + data.toString());
}
```

Comment: I think XiaoMi OS might has a battery optimization that when you swipe the app in recently tabs, it will close app totally including the app's services. So you may try to set your GCM message's `priority` to high.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @bjiang. How do I set the GCM message priority to high? But you are right that swiping the app stops my services. Weirdly enough, it happens to WeChat as well, but their services restarts itself right after.

Comment: To set priority, add a priority field as a sibling of data, and set it to "high" or "normal".

Comment: On the server side when sending out the GCM JSON? @ArthurThompson

Comment: Did you found any solution for this problem ?